# Wordpress: set ul menu class based on parent li class

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

How can I do that? I am working on a custom menu funcitonality, I know I have to work with the start_lvl

```
public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        $classes = get_parent_menu_item_classes(); // I NEED SOMETHING LIKE THIS
    if ( in_array( 'column-header', $classes ) ) { // get the classes here
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\" class=\" nav nav-list\">\n";
    } else {
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\" class=\" dropdown-menu\">\n";
    }
}
```

Please advise :)

Comment: Where is your `$classes` array defined or coming from?

Comment: Well that is exactly why I am asking here.

Comment: Are you actually trying to define a dropdown menu based on the class name *column-header* or, technically speaking, are you trying to define a dropdown menu if that `ul` actually has children?

Comment: No no. I am just trying to give the ul child a class based on his li parent. That is all.

Comment: I found a way to track the parent class, the answer is right here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62054/custom-walker-how-to-get-id-in-function-start-lvl